# Initializing Instance Variable as an Array - Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, initialization, instance-variables

I'm trying to initialize and instance variable as an array as follows:

```
  class Arch < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessor :name1

    def initialize
      @name1 = []
    end

    def add_name1(t)
      @name1 << t
    end

  end
```

When I try Arch.new in a console session I get (Object doesn't support #inspect). What's up? How do I make an instance array variable? I tried to follow [this](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html) like so:

```
class Arch < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :name1

  def after_initialize
    @name1 = []
  end

  def add_name1(t)
    @name1 << t
  end

end
```

and my @name1 was still a NilClass. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are overriding ActiveRecord's `initialize` method. Try using `super`:

```
def initialize(*args, &block)
   super 
   @name1 = []
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overiding the `initialize` method of `ActiveRecord::Base`. When creating a new instance of your class only your initilize will be called. All the instance variables that `ActiveRecord::Base` would have created are uninitialized and `#inspect` fails. In order to fix this you need to call the constructor of your base class (using `super`)

```
class Arch < ActiveRecord::Base  

  attr_accessor :name1
  def initialize
    super
    @name1 = []
  end

  def add_name1(t)
    @name1 << t
  end
end
```