# How to initialize an Active Record attribute in after_initialize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**user.rb**

```
after_initialize :init

private

    def init
        self.name ||= 'Bob'
    end
```

**irb**

```
irb> User.select('id')
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

If I change the callback to `before_validation` then the above query works.

Ideally I would like to be able to keep the initialization in `after_initialize`. Is there a way to achieve this?

I would prefer not to have to [override the `initialize` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8073067/664833).

Comment: Have you tried doing just e.g., `User.first`? I don't know if `select` actually (or fully) instantiates an `AR::Base` object...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that makes you think `after_initialize` is a solution?

Answer (score -1):

The posted code is trying to set the name *every time* a user is instantiated (such as User.new, User.first, User.all )

If you intend to save the record with `name = "Bob"` when `name` is nil, do it in `before_validation`, or `after_validation`.

If you intend to merely return "Bob" when `name` is nil, do it in the getter:

```
  def name
    @name ||= "Bob"
  end
```

Comment: Why the negative vote? I'll like to understand if I misunderstood the question, my answer is wrong, what I said is wrong or it is against the rules or ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have yet to determine whether your answer will be suitable in my situation. Anyway, I didn't downvote - and I hate it when people downvote without writing their reasoning in a comment.